# knitr package loading error stringr

Tags: r, knitr, package

I get the following error:

`1Error in library(stringr) : 
  Package 'stringr' version 1.2.0 cannot be unloaded`

when loading the following packages in my knitr document:

`library(checkpoint)
checkpoint("2017-01-01")
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(readr)
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)
library(xtable)
library(zoo)
library(gridExtra)`

when I remove `stringr` then I get the error:

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "str_sub"`

...any ideas? I am using Mac OSX Mavericks. I copied the files over from a Windows 7 (where it worked) and I'm assuming that has something to do with it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `str_sub` is a function from `stringr`, if you remove it, then you can't use the function.

Comment: open console and check if the `library(stringr)` gives you error

Comment: @KevinArseneau Yes, I understand that in general...however I do have stringr installed @Hadrikgupta and can load it separately in an R Script or in the console...I am thinking it has something to do with a dependency on one of the other packages? I have seen similar questions that just say update the package however I am using MRO with `checkpoint` so that doesn't really apply...

Comment: @Prevost, I agree. And tbh, you likely have a conflict in your code resulting from a conflict by using `checkpoint`. `stringr` version 1.2.0 was published after (2017-02-18) your checkpoint date of 2017-01-01.

Comment: @KevinArseneau That sounds like a good reason to have an issue...I will try updating the `checkpoint` date. I don't have an issue when I load it all on Windows...which seems incorrect because how can I load a package that doesn't exist on CRAN unless `checkpoint` is not loading the packages correctly on my Windows...

Comment: @KevinArseneau If you post that as your solution I will mark it correct. That my `checkpoint` date was before `stringr` was created.

Comment: @KevinArseneau Also not sure if this is general knowledge, but when loading packages using `checkpoint` the `checkpoint` server may not respond for several hours ie none of the packages will be detected or installed via `checkpoint`. Then once it reaches it works properly and the packages are loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conflict due to the `stringr` package being newer (*2017-02-18*) than your `checkpoint` date of *2017-01-01*.

You could clear the conflict by moving the date you use to something later, *i.e.*

```
checkpoint("2017-02-18") # or later
```

Alternatively, if you find you have mixed dependencies that rely on packages that were not all current on the same date, I would recommend having a look at `packrat` ([link](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)), which is designed for that purpose.